# Tikz: use opacity for fill, yet leave draw (lines) untouched

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

When I use the tikz key `opacity` for a polygon in a tikzpicture, it applies to the drawn fill as well as to the draw lines.

I would like to have it this way that the lines remain untouched by the `opacity` key, so that they behave as if they had `opacity=1`.

(What I do now is redraw the polygon with `fill=none`, but that is a crippled solution to the problem).

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can specify the `fill opacity` separately from the `draw opacity`. In the first example below I used `opacity` and in the second I used `fill opacity` which will only affect the `fill` and not the `draw`.

[image]

### Note:

- As pointed out by Martin Scharrer: Specifying `\opacity=<x>` affects the `fill`, `draw` and `text` so is equivalent to saying `fill opacity=<X>, draw opacity=<X>, text opacity=<X>`.
- `fill opacity` applies not only to the fill, but also applies to text. To override this behavior, you can separately set the `text opacity` which applies only to the text labels. So, apply `text opacity=1` to ensure that opacity is not applied to the text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick, draw=black, fill=yellow, opacity=0.2]
       (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick, draw=black, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2]
       (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `opacity=<X>` is just a short-cut for `fill opacity=<X>,draw opacity=<X>`. Both are actual to different low-level settings in the output file (e.g. PDF).

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Good point. Have added a note incorporating your comment.

Comment: wow, sometimes things can be so easy... I thought I had already tried that. Great!

Comment: Note that when there is text inside the node, it will also fade. Use `text opacity=1`.

Comment: @oarfish: That was the intent of the second bullet point, but have expanded to make it more explicit.

Comment: Unfortunately TikZ does not seem to be able to handle transparencies separeately in a transparency group, e.g., `transparency group, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1` will not work as expected.

Comment: @cgogolin: I don't have experience with `transparency group`s so I recommend you post a new question with a  fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.