# Precisely placing a letter on another with tikz

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to design a logo using tikz although I'm a total beginner.  I pretty much would like to show 2 capital letters each with a lowercase letter placed on it's vertical leg.

I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [anchor=base, scale=5] (0,0) {EF} ;
  \node (s) [fill=white,scale=.8] at (-.9,.9) {e};
  \node [right=.95cm of s,fill=white,scale=.8] {f};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: imageEF]

1. Is there a way to precisely change the space between the two letters E and F?  I'd like to have them almost touching each other.

   I suspect the best approach would be first to glue the lower case letter on top of it's capital letter and then place each entity to a specific distance of each other.  But I don't know how to do that.
2. Besides, how can I make sure to place the lowercase letters in the middle of the thick vertical leg of the capital letters?
3. I would also like the box around the lowercase letters to be as small as possible.  Could this box be a circle instead of a rectangle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try a few values until you get the desired results:

[image]

As requested in the comments, here is an example with opacity applied to the main text as well as well as the lower case inserted text:

[image]

### References:

- [Tikz: use opacity for fill, yet leave draw (lines) untouched](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39037/tikz-use-opacity-for-fill-yet-leave-draw-lines-untouched)

### Notes:

- A `\kern` was applied to get the `F` right *just* touching the `E`.
- I would recommend using units of length that will scale with the fonts used: `em` for horizontal and `ex` for vertical.
- An `inner sep` was applied to set the separation around the imbedded characters,
- The `shape=circle` makes the nodes circular as desired.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [anchor=base, scale=5] (0,0) {E\kern-0.1175em F} ;
  \node (s) [fill=white,scale=.8, inner sep=0.025pt, shape=circle] at (-2.15em,5.9ex) {e};
  \node [right=2.245em of s,fill=white,scale=.8, inner sep=0.15pt, shape=circle] {f};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: with opacity applied

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [anchor=base, scale=5, , text opacity=0.6, color=brown] (0,0) {E\kern-0.1175em F} ;
  \node (s) [fill=white,scale=.8, inner sep=0.025pt, shape=circle] at (-2.15em,5.9ex) {e};
  \node [right=2.245em of s,fill=white,scale=.8, inner sep=0.15pt, shape=circle, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1] {f};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I force the background to be transparent, both the main frame as well as the circles holding the lower case letter?

Comment: @Rene: See revised solution which now includes opacity.

Comment: Yes but with such a solution the circle holding the lowercase letters
cannot be fully transparent.Actually, I would want to have the whole background including the circle holding the lowercase letters (i.e., white part in your first solution) fully transparent.

Comment: @Rene: I think you just need to adjust the opacity level. If that is not what you want, please update the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

This uses stacks instead of `tikz`.  The inter-letter kerning, as well as the vertical and horizontal offset distances of the inset letters can be changed.  The `l` and `b` indicate the insets are relative to the left-bottom of the base image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{1.00pt}{b}{3.8pt}{\smash{\stackon[-1.5pt]{\scalebox{.33}
  {\textcolor{white}{$\bullet$}}}{\scalebox{.15}{\strut e}}}}{E}%
\kern-1pt%
\stackinset{l}{1.00pt}{b}{3.8pt}{\smash{\stackon[-1.65pt]{\scalebox{.33}
  {\textcolor{white}{$\bullet$}}}{\scalebox{.15}{\strut f\,}}}}{F}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an alternative interpretation of your request, using inverse colors rather than a circle or box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{1.34pt}{b}{3.5pt}{\scalebox{.2}{\textcolor{white}{\strut e}}}{E}%
\kern-1pt%
\stackinset{l}{1.40pt}{b}{3.5pt}{\scalebox{.2}{\textcolor{white}{\strut f}}}{F}
\end{document}
```

[image]