# Make elements of a tikz drawing less opaque (more transparent)

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I have the following figure in Tikz, could you help me to make some parts of this figure more transparant? Something like the attached figures.
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\sf \scriptsize,
>=LaTeX,
cell/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, fill=green!15, draw,very thick,},
operator/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=-0.5pt,minimum height =0.5cm, fill=red!10, font = \large}, 
block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, 
    minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em, font = \LARGE},
bl/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, rotate=90,
minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em, font = \LARGE}
sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.01pt, node contents={}}
function/.style={ellipse, draw,inner sep=1pt},
ct/.style={circle,draw,line width = .75pt,minimum width=1cm,inner sep=1pt,},
gt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=4mm,minimum height=3mm,inner sep=1pt},
dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.001mm, fill=black!15, node contents={}},
mylabel/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
ArrowC1/.style={rounded corners=.25cm,thick,},
ArrowC2/.style={rounded corners=.5cm,thick,},
ArrowC3/.style={rounded corners=.1cm,thick,},
dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.01pt, node contents={}},
alr/.style = {Stealth-Stealth},
arr/.style = {-Stealth},]
\node [cell, minimum height =4.5cm, minimum width=7.4cm] at (2.7,-1.7){} ;
\node[operator, name = operator] {$\times$};
\node[operator, right = 3cm of operator ] (plus) {+};
\node[block, below = 2cm of operator] (kapa1) {$\kappa$};
\node[block, below = 2cm of plus] (kapa2) {$\tilde{\kappa}$};
\node[block, right = 0.35cm of kapa1] (kapa3) {$\kappa$};
\node[block, right = 0.35cm of kapa2] (kapa4) {$\kappa$};
\node[operator, above = 0.4cm of kapa4] (time2) {$\times$};
\node[operator, above = 0.7cm of kapa2 ] (times) {$\times$};
\node[block, above = 0.4cm of time2] (kapa5) {$\tilde{\kappa}$};
\node (dot1) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa1]{};
\node (dot2) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa2]{};
\node (dot3) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa3]{};
\node (dot4) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa4]{};
\node (dot5) [dot,left= 1.3cm of operator]{};
\node (dot6) [dot,left= 1.6cm of dot1]{};
\node (dot7) [dot,right= 0.6cm of time2]{};
\node (dot8) [dot,above= 2.8cm of dot7]{};
\node (dot9) [dot,left= 1cm of dot1]{};
\node[output, right = 3.21cm of plus] (ct) {$c(t)$};
\node (dot10) [dot,below= 0.8cm of dot9]{};
\node (dot11) [dot,left= 0.6cm of dot1]{};
\node[output, right = 0.8cm of dot7, font = \large] (h_t) {};
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa1) -- node[pos = 0.405, right, font = \Large]{$\varrho_t$}(operator); 
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa2) -- node[pos = 0.405,  right, font = \Large]{$\tilde{c}_t$}(times); 
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (times) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus); 
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa4) -- node[pos = 0.505,  right, font = \Large]{$o_t$}(time2);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa5);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot1) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa1);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa2);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot3) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa3);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot4) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa4);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot1) -- node{}(dot4);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (operator) -- node{}(plus);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot6) -| node{}(kapa4);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa3) |- node[pos = 0.505,  above right, font = \Large]{$I_t$}(times);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot6) |- node[above, font = \Large]{$c_{t-1}$}(dot1);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(operator);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm, red] (kapa5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm, red ] (kapa5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus);
\draw[ arr, line width=0.30mm, ] (dot5) -- node[above left, font = \Large]{$h_{t-1}$}(operator);
\draw[ line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(dot7);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot7) -- node[pos = 0.905, right, font = \Large]{$h_t$}(dot8);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos= 0.8,above right, font = \Large]{$h_t$}(h_t);
\draw[ArrowC2, line width=0.30mm] (dot10) |- node[pos= -.16, , font = \Large]{$x_t$}(dot11);
\draw[arr, line width=0.30mm, red] (kapa5) |- node[pos= 0.9,above right, font = \Large]{$c_t$}(ct);
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Would [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39039/167081) help!?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's a simple example and its only works for the cases where there is nothing the block. But I have a lot things on my block.

Comment: you do have lots of components. You can simply add `opacity=0.2` to the components you would like to lower the opacity of. Also, I don't know which components you need to make less visible. Would you like to update the question!?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just update some part of the figure which I want to high light. I've shown them as red. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I can only see the top-right arrow with the text. Is there anything else? Also, would you like the red portion to be less visible?

Comment: Yes. only the top right is highlighted. No. The red part will be highlighted and the other less visible.

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing the title since I believe that you confuse "blurry" with "transparent".

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks. Yes, your phrase is better:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most of the components needs to be less visible, add `opacity=0.25` to the options of `tikzpicture`. This will make everything less visible. Now, individually go to the components that you would like to have them visible and add `opacity=1`. This will override the option of value `0.25`.
[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    opacity=0.25,
    font=\sf \scriptsize,
    >=LaTeX,
    cell/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, fill=green!15, draw,very thick,},
    operator/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=-0.5pt,minimum height =0.5cm, fill=red!10, font = \large},
    block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle,
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em, font = \LARGE},
    bl/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, rotate=90,
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em, font = \LARGE}
    sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, circle, node distance=1cm},
    input/.style={coordinate},
    output/.style={coordinate},
    dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.01pt, node contents={}}
    function/.style={ellipse, draw,inner sep=1pt},
    ct/.style={circle,draw,line width = .75pt,minimum width=1cm,inner sep=1pt,},
    gt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=4mm,minimum height=3mm,inner sep=1pt},
    dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.001mm, fill=black!15, node contents={}},
    mylabel/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    ArrowC1/.style={rounded corners=.25cm,thick,},
    ArrowC2/.style={rounded corners=.5cm,thick,},
    ArrowC3/.style={rounded corners=.1cm,thick,},
    dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.01pt, node contents={}},
    alr/.style = {Stealth-Stealth},
    arr/.style = {-Stealth},]
    \node [cell, minimum height =4.5cm, minimum width=7.4cm,opacity=1] at (2.7,-1.7){} ;
    \node[operator, name = operator] {$\times$};
    \node[operator, right = 3cm of operator ] (plus) {+};
    \node[block, below = 2cm of operator] (kapa1) {$\kappa$};
    \node[block, below = 2cm of plus] (kapa2) {$\tilde{\kappa}$};
    \node[block, right = 0.35cm of kapa1] (kapa3) {$\kappa$};
    \node[block, right = 0.35cm of kapa2] (kapa4) {$\kappa$};
    \node[operator, above = 0.4cm of kapa4] (time2) {$\times$};
    \node[operator, above = 0.7cm of kapa2 ] (times) {$\times$};
    \node[block, above = 0.4cm of time2] (kapa5) {$\tilde{\kappa}$};
    \node (dot1) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa1]{};
    \node (dot2) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa2]{};
    \node (dot3) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa3]{};
    \node (dot4) [dot,below= 0.5cm of kapa4]{};
    \node (dot5) [dot,left= 1.3cm of operator]{};
    \node (dot6) [dot,left= 1.6cm of dot1]{};
    \node (dot7) [dot,right= 0.6cm of time2]{};
    \node (dot8) [dot,above= 2.8cm of dot7]{};
    \node (dot9) [dot,left= 1cm of dot1]{};
    \node[output, right = 3.21cm of plus] (ct) {$c(t)$};
    \node (dot10) [dot,below= 0.8cm of dot9]{};
    \node (dot11) [dot,left= 0.6cm of dot1]{};
    \node[output, right = 0.8cm of dot7, font = \large] (h_t) {};
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa1) -- node[pos = 0.405, right, font = \Large]{$\varrho_t$}(operator);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa2) -- node[pos = 0.405,  right, font = \Large]{$\tilde{c}_t$}(times);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (times) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa4) -- node[pos = 0.505,  right, font = \Large]{$o_t$}(time2);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa5);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot1) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa1);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa2);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot3) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa3);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot4) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(kapa4);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot1) -- node{}(dot4);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (operator) -- node{}(plus);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot6) -| node{}(kapa4);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (kapa3) |- node[pos = 0.505,  above right, font = \Large]{$I_t$}(times);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot6) |- node[above, font = \Large]{$c_{t-1}$}(dot1);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm] (dot5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(operator);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm, red, opacity=1] (kapa5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm, red, opacity=1 ] (kapa5) |- node[pos = 0.405]{}(plus);
    \draw[ arr, line width=0.30mm, ] (dot5) -- node[above left, font = \Large]{$h_{t-1}$}(operator);
    \draw[ line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos = 0.405]{}(dot7);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (dot7) -- node[pos = 0.905, right, font = \Large]{$h_t$}(dot8);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm] (time2) -- node[pos= 0.8,above right, font = \Large]{$h_t$}(h_t);
    \draw[ArrowC2, line width=0.30mm] (dot10) |- node[pos= -.16, , font = \Large]{$x_t$}(dot11);
    \draw[arr, line width=0.30mm, red, opacity=1] (kapa5) |- node[pos= 0.9,above right, font = \Large]{$c_t$}(ct);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome :)!