# Color and opacity of \Rightarrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows, transparency

I need to draw an arrow that looks like the usual `\Rightarrow` but has a blue outline with 0.5 opacity. I can get this far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1.5,-0.7) rectangle (1.5,0.7);
    \draw[-{implies}, double equal sign distance, blue] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: arrow1]

As soon as I change the opacity, though, this happens:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1.5,-0.7) rectangle (1.5,0.7);
    \draw[-{implies}, double equal sign distance, blue, opacity = 0.5] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: arrow2]

Is there something wrong with my syntax, or is this an unavoidable behavior of this kind of arrow?

Comment: [transparency - Tikz: use opacity for fill, yet leave draw (lines) untouched - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39037/tikz-use-opacity-for-fill-yet-leave-draw-lines-untouched) perhaps

Comment: Never use `arrows` - it has been deprecated many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can never work. You need to ask a question about what you want to achieve.

To get rid of the effect, you talk about, you can use a `transparency group` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pattern[pattern=checkerboard] (-1.5,-0.7) rectangle (1.5,0.7);
\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
\draw[-{Implies}, double equal sign distance, blue] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Light blue double arrow]

But with something in the background(the only reason to make something transparent)

[image: Double arrow with mixed colors on checker board]

It can be seen that the middle of the double line is not empty but filled with the background color(white) and this covers the pattern.

A double line is really just drawing twice - first a fat blue line and then a center white line.

---

*Edit:* I suppose that it works with a `transparency group` in the particular case where the thing in the background is not behind the center of the double line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-1,0.4) to[bend right] (1,0.25);
\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
\draw[-{Implies}, double equal sign distance, blue, very thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Light blue double line with a black area]

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Comment: @LorenzoRiva: Strange - I am making the argument that it does not work. I am curious of what you your use case is!?

Comment: Just found that you can use `nfold` see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709938/8650

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. Since all I wanted was for the contour of my arrow to be blue and slightly transparent I used your first example with `transparency group`. It appears on a white background so the issue you bring up does not occur. Thank you!

Comment: But you *must* have something else in the background otherwise it does not make sense to make the arrow transparent. It is like installing a window right in front of a brick wall - no nothing to be seen.

Comment: Aaaah, I see what's happening. There are two distinct arrows I need to draw in the picture I want. The first is a normal blue arrow with 0.5 opacity that crosses a red label (which is in the foreground). The second is the `Implies` arrow with blue contour. Strictly speaking the latter does not need to be transparent because it is not crossing anything in the foreground, but I would like its contour to have the same shade of blue as the first arrow. So either 1. I use your method to achieve the same color while adding unnecessary transparency, or 2. I find a way to match the blue...

Comment: ... in the second arrow to the toned down blue in the first arrow. I know I should go for the second method but I am worried about a different part of my paper at the moment and so I don't really feel like scouring the TikZ documentation for the correct commands.