# tikz-cd "equal" arrow with a colored background

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, backgrounds

I use a Beamer template with black background. Whenever I type an `equal` arrow with `tikzcd`, it appears as a large white line (because some background is added between the two lines of the "equal", and this background is white by default):

[image: i dont want this]

How can I get a correct background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `tikzcd` uses Ti*k*Z's `double` option. As I found out in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325388/tikz-double-line-core-color-transparency#comment1106063_325410), this option has an optional parameter specifying the background color separating the two lines of the "equal".

In the `tikzcd` environment, just replace

```
\arrow[equal]{r}
```

with

```
\arrow[equal, double=black]{r}
```

which produces the correct output:

[image: i want this]

Answer (score 6):

Use the `nfold` library, so you don't need to guess the background color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{blue!90!red}{%
  \color{white}%
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] A \arrow[r,equal,nfold] \& B \end{tikzcd}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice - first time I hear about `nfold`

Comment: @hpekristiansen It's of course slower, but it solves a very important issue with double lines, particularly the curved ones. But also the straight ones showed artifacts.

Comment: Just read the full manual - I see many benefits. I answered a question today that might have benefitted from `nfold` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709865/color-and-opacity-of-rightarrow-in-tikz/709894#709894